# Errors with Alert Views

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have an error when I run my code: It says undeclared identifier of 'alertView' for this line of code:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView* )alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {

        if(buttonIndex==0) 
        else if(butonIndex==1)

    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean you are getting the error when you compile, not when you run, correct? Where is this code? Is the error on the first line of the code you posted?

Comment: You are not even stating your development platform.  Anyway, I would do some homework about UIAlertView if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

It goes something like the following.

```
- (void)dismissPop2:(NSString *)projectname {
    projectdelete = projectname;
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to delete this project (%@)?",projectname];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"- Project deletion -"
                                                message:msg
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
    [alert setTag:100];
    [alert show];
}

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView { // Validation
    if ([alertView tag] == 100) {
        return YES;
    }

    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([alertView tag] == 100) {
    // Deleting a project
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Do something since the user has tapped YES
    }
}
```

If it doesn't help, then you should show more work.

Comment: Well This is the whole thing I wrote so far:   if (_targetsDestroyed > 10) {
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"You Win!" message:@"You Won the Game!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];

        }
        
        -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView* )alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        {
            
            if(buttonIndex==0)
                else if(butonIndex==1)
                    
                    }

        return;
    }

        
}
}

@end

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a syntax error earlier in your code that is breaking the parser. Check to make sure the function above the one you posted is closed with a }, all [] are matched, and statements end with a ;

If you post a bit more, someone could probably point it out, but I'm sure you can find it by reading your code.